# Rails don't allow attribute to update under a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Say i’m updating an attribute called `status`.  I don’t want the `status` to be able to be able to be updated when it’s currently `cancelled` or `complete`.  How could I not allow this, but allow `status` to be updated otherwise?

Comment: If I read this correctly, if you mark a status cancelled or complete,  you want to lock that attribute from being changed permenantly? Suppose you mark one canceled by mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `before_update` callback.

```
   before_update :prevent_update_if_status_canceled_or_completed?

  private

  def prevent_update_if_status_canceled_or_completed?
    if status == 'canceled' || status == 'complete'
      self.errors.add_to_base "Cannot update a completed or canceled record "
      false
    else 
      true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [transitions gem](https://github.com/troessner/transitions). It's quite neat.

Comment: I'm using state_machine which is similar.  I couldn't find any info in the docs that will filter the updates.  Does transitions have that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check while creating a status for that user.

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  unless @user.status == "cancelled" || @user.status == "completed"
    @status = @user.statuses.new(status_params)
    if @status.save!
      respond_to do |format|
        ...
        #status created logic, render desired content to user
      end
    end
  else
    #Handle status not created logic
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you've a `update` method like:

```
def update
  params[:model_name].delete :status if @model_name.status == "cancelled"
  @model_name = @model_name.update(model_params) # model_params are the parameters you're allowing with strong parameters.
  .....
end
```

Delete the `status` from the strong parameter with a conditional statement.

or, you can create a `private` method for excluding the `status` from being updated.

```
def except_satatus_params
  params[:model_name].except(:status)
end
```

then use this method on the controller with a check that if `@model.status` is previously `cancelled` or `complete`.

Comment: Having methods that are coupled to your model, like callbacks is bad enough, overriding active record methods is even worse.